# R: Retrieving participant scores from another table based on birth dates

Tags: r, date, bins

I have two tables: One with participants and one with an encoding of scores based on birth dates.
The score table looks like this:

```
score_table

Key        |  Value
--------------------
01/01/1900 |  15
01/01/1940 |  25
01/01/1950 |  30
```

All participants with birth dates between 01/01/1900 and 01/01/1940 should get a score of 15.
Participants born between 01/01/1940 and 01/01/1950 should get a score of 25, etc.

My participants' table looks like this:

```
participant_table

BirthDate    |   Gender
-----------------------
05/05/1930   |   M
02/07/1954   |   V
01/11/1941   |   U
```

I would like to add a score to get the output table:

```
BirthDate    |   Gender   |   Score
------------------------------------
05/05/1930   |   M        |   15
02/07/1954   |   V        |   30
01/11/1941   |   U        |   25
```

I built several solutions for similar problems when the exact values are in the score table (using dplyr::left_join or base::match) or for numbers which can be rounded to another value. Here, the intervals are irregular and the dates arbitrary.

I know I can build a solution by iterating through the score table, using this method:

```
as.Date("05/05/1930", format="%d/%m/%Y) < as.Date("01/01/1900", format="%d/%m/%Y)
```

Which returns a Boolean and thus allows me to walk through the scores until I find a date which is bigger and then use the last score. However, there must be a better way to do this.

Maybe I can create some sort of bins from the dataframe, as such:

```
Bin 1           | Bin 2           | Bin 3
Date 1 : Date 2 | Date 2 : Date 3 | Date 3 : inf
```

But I don't yet see how. Does anyone see an efficient way to create such bins from a dataframe, so that I can efficiently retrieve scores from this table?

**MRE:**

Score table:

```
structure(list(key=c("1/1/1900", "2/1/2013", "2/1/2014","2/1/2015", "4/1/2016", "4/1/2017"), value=c(65,65,67,67,67,68)), row.names=1:6, class="data.frame")
```

Participant File:

```
structure(list(birthDate=c("10/10/1968", "6/5/2015","10/10/2017"), Gender=c("M", "U", "F")), row.names=1:3, class="data.frame")
```

Goal File:

```
structure(list(birthDate=c("10/10/1968", "6/5/2015","10/10/2017"), Gender=c("M", "U", "F"), Score = c(65,67,68)), row.names=1:3, class="data.frame")
```

---

Comment: It looks like the scores are associated with decades?! Can't we just add a new variable, denoting the decade (e.g 1930, 1940) and use that to join the two data sets?

Comment: If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) I'll give it a try. (A MRE makes it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question)

Comment: I added a simple MRE

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `lag()` along with `sqldf`:

```
score_table$Key2 <- as.Date(lead(score_table$Key), format="%d/%m/%Y")
score_table$Key <- as.Date(score_table$Key, format="%d/%m/%Y")
names(score_table) <- c("Date1", "Value", "Date2")
participant_table$BirthDate <- as.Date(participant_table$BirthDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")
sql <- "SELECT p.BirthDate, p.Gender, s.Value AS Score
        FROM participant_table p
        INNER JOIN score_table s
            ON (p.BirthDate >= s.Date1 OR s.Date1 IS NULL) AND
               (p.BirthDate < s.Date2 OR s.Date2 IS NULL)"
participant_table <- sqldf(sql)
```

The logic here is to join the participant to the score table using a *range* of matching dates in the latter.  For the edge cases of the first and last rows of the score table, we allow a missing date in either column to represent any date whatsoever.  For example, in the last row of the score table, the only requirement for a match is that a date be greater than the lower portion of the range.

I actually do not have R running locally at the moment, but here is a demo link to SQLite showing that the SQL logic works correctly:

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Consider defining `Key2` in the SQL steatement:  `participant_table$BirthDate <- as.Date(participant_table$BirthDate, format = "%d/%m/%Y");
score_table$Key <- as.Date(score_table$Key, format = "%d/%m/%Y");
sql <- "with s2 as (
  select *, lag(Key, -1) over() as Key2 from score_table
)
SELECT p.BirthDate, p.Gender, s.Value AS Score
        FROM participant_table p
        INNER JOIN s2 s
            ON (p.BirthDate >= s.Key OR s.Key IS NULL) AND
               (p.BirthDate < s.Key2 OR s.Key2 IS NULL)"; 
sqldf(sql)`

Comment: The Logic is exactly what I am looking for! However, The Minicran Snapshot which I have to use does not include sqldf... I am going to try and get that organised though, as I don't see a clear R-way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very simple solution using only arithmetic.

In order to retrieve a score, I check how many numbers are superseded by the input date:

```
rownum <- sum(as.Date(input_date, format="%d/%m/%Y") > 
              as.Date(score_table$Key, format="%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Then, the corresponding key can be found using:

```
score <- score_table[["Value"]][rownum]
```

Thus, the spacing of the dates becomes irrelevant and it works quite fast.
I thought I'd share my solution in case it might be of use.
Thanks everyone for the effort and responses!